# .Net Core 3 Identity register or login links not functional

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

MAC OS .Net Core 3 or 3.1 NOT using DefaultUI

Identity Register or Login links just flash

So, create an MVC app without using Identity initially

```
dotnet new mvc --auth None -n vacate

dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

Add in Identity and do not specify DefaultUI

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --userClass ApplicationUser  --dbContext ApplicationDbContext --useSqLite
```

Compile and run the app.
Nope...

First, fix the missing using statement in Register.cshtml.cs
add:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
```

Compile and run the app.
Nope...

Now, add in the partial tag for LoginPartial in _Layout.cshtml

```
  <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
```

Ok...

Now Compile and run the app...
Try to click on Register or Login links and they just flick the browser with no action...

What's missing to get Identity to work without using DefaultUI (ie no RazorLib)??

Comment: @Kirk Larkin - I saw the other post - can I also just add the Account and Manage Controllers to handle the routes?

Comment: The scaffolding is all Razor Pages, so there's no out-of-the-box MVC based versions. If you're planning to create them yourself, then sure, you could set them up to use the same routes and it'd work. Do you have specific requirement to avoid the RP version?

Comment: Then add  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); to the configure method;remove all endpoint related code and write you email sender per the docs.